# Dynamically add functions to window.onscroll?

Tags: javascript

I know that i can only call once the `window.onscroll = function(){}`, because calling it multiple times may cause that they will overwrite each other. That's why i ask: it's possible to "push" function calls to window.onscroll?

```js
//example
function example(num) {
  var number = num;
  window.onscroll = function() {
    number *= number
  }
}
example(2);
example(4);
//this way, the number only changes in the second function call
//somehow it's possible to get the same result? ("adding" functions to window.onscroll
function example(num) {
  var number = num;
  window.onscroll += function() {
    number *= number
  }
}
example(2);
example(4);
```

How it's possible to "add" function calls to window.onscroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible by using the [addEventListener API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

e.g.:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  console.log('one');
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  console.log('two');
});
```

For example, in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmzdJL), I bound two scroll listeners to the `window` object. If you open the browser console and scroll the preview pane at the bottom, you should see both messages repeating in the console.